# Ref/Reactive as store

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

Is it good idea to use ref or reactive as your store?

what I'm talking about is that I will create some JS file, export ref variable from there , so i can use it anywhere in my code

```
// counter.store.js
export const counter = ref(0)
```

```
// counter.vue

<script setup>
import {counter} from './counter.store.js'
</script>

<template> 

<span> {{ counter }} </span>
<button @click="counter++"> Add </button>

</template>
```

Is there any downside of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Vue reactivity primitives to create simple global store is perfectly fine and it is even described in Vue docs - [Simple State Management with Reactivity API](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html#simple-state-management-with-reactivity-api)

Main drawbacks are:

1. no support in Vue Dev Tools (so for example looking at the component in Dev Tools you are not able to tell what is components internal state and what comes from the global store)
2. [possible issues](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html#ssr-considerations) in SSR scenarios
3. suboptimal dev experience - Hot Module Replacement not working

Answer (score -2):

It is good to use **reactive** as your store for simple projects, and when the logic behind it isn't so complex. But you also need to know when to not, where making use of **Pinia** or **Vuex** is better(In situation where management becomes complex as the application grows, which ends up making debugging challenging)

More detailed explanation is provided in the Vue Docs on how to use **reactive** and **Pinia**, and the reason for using Pinia and not **Vuex** - https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html